# Apple App Store: Publish your game under your organization name

Tags: ios, publishing

I am in the process of building a mobile game targeting Apple App Store. This is a co-op work done by me and my teammate. We do not want to publish the game under my personal Apple developer account, but rather use our fantasy org name (let's call it a game dev studio).

Is there a way of doing this without going through the hassle of founding a company? Do I need to get another Apple account type (other than individual person)?